# ADIRU Mounting in Avionics Rack

Tags: navigation, avionics

If I understand correctly, navigational gyroscopes and accelerometers are located within the ADIRU boxes themselves. In order to initialise during aircraft startup, they must be mounted precisely along a aircraft's reference axes.

My question is this: since the gyroscopes/accelerometers are inside the ADIRU box, and the box is mounted on the avionics rack, does that imply that the avionics rack itself must be precisely aligned with the aircraft's axes? If not, are the ADIRUs mounted on special, "high precision" racks? And if not that, maybe a software algorithm can compensate for small physical deviations between the ADIRU box and the aircraft's reference axes?

Edit:

By the way, ADIRUs can initialise just fine if the ground is slanted (and it often is). Similarly, it is also fine if the aircraft is tilted in any direction relative to the ground (depending on the cargo/fuel loading). What I am talking about is strictly the physical alignment of the ADIRU relative to the aircraft axes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have said in your question is correct.

Boresighting is the name of the process which you are referring. It involves a special jig you attach to the aircraft and plumb-bobs/lasers. This is a task performed by avionics maintenance engineers. I've not worked on cars, but I would imagine it's like doing an extremely accurate wheel alignment, but if you screw it up, the aircraft's primary source of navigation will be broken.

The ADIRU is likely to be mounted on a precisely aligned mounting plate on the avionics rack (although some modern ADIRUs don't require this plate to be aligned mechanically and will align and compensate themselves). You essentially adjust the level of the plate using shims which are special close tolerance washers of varying thickness. You use reference points on the aircraft to calculate any errors and gradually null any errors out as best you can. After this, some systems also have an electronic boresight compensation panel which can add or subtract any remaining error after the mechanical adjustment. This works by mixing the compensator signals with the gyros and accelerometer outputs. There is an adjustment for aircraft's three major axes (lateral, longitudinal, vertical). There are thumb switches to set these figures and if I recall correctly they go up in 0.5 minute increments. We didn't like there being any values larger than +/- 3.0 minutes. I'm faily certain that's the unit of measurement but you will have to give me a pass if I am wrong because it has been a while... Military aircraft may also have compensations for the gun, weapons RADAR, Head Up Display, etc. because you want to be able to shoot straight as well as fly straight. When a military pilot isn't very good at dropping dumb bombs, they like to blame the boresighting rather than admit they are the one with the issue. If the boresighting is an issue, it presents as a good tight grouping of dropped bombs but they are all 30m+ away from the bullseye. In many ways, boresighting isn't that dissimilar to zeroing a rifle scope.

The boresight process gets the ADIRU lined up accurately to the aircraft and the compensator figures are recorded in the maintenance documentation. It is possible to see if a pilot has overstressed the aircraft because the new figures could be way out from last time. Or maybe somebody accidently started undoing the ADIRU thumb screws on the mounting plate, bumping the system out of alignment. Look but don't touch! The boresight process isn't fun. Can take a whole shift sometimes and nobody is allowed to get on the aircraft except for the boresight crew. If somebody crosses the bollards and messes with the jet while you were on a break, start the whole process again. *"But I just had to check the fuel total..."*, "NO TOUCHY!!!!!" *SLAP*

When you switch the ADIRU on, it goes through a process of alignment. The process usually takes about 8 minutes during which time you may not move the aircraft. It is common to inhibit the fine alignment from occurring if the park brake isn't set. The gyros will use the gravitational force and the 15 degree rotation of the Earth per hour to align. After this time, you can flick the switch to NAV mode and it will track where you are using dead reckoning.

Comment: Amazing - many interesting points here. Thank you!